# Electric field inside a homogenous distribution for slightly different Coulomb's law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, voltage, differentiation

I am trying to show that the electric field inside a homogeneous distribution of superficial charge is of the order of magnitude of $\delta$, with:
$$V(\textbf{r})=\int d^3\textbf{r'}\frac{\rho(\textbf{r}')}{|\textbf{r-r'}|^{1+\delta}}$$

The electric field can be found as $E=-\nabla V$, but the notation throws me off. This is what I tried:
$$E=-\frac{d}{dr}\left(\int d^3\textbf{r'}\frac{\rho(\textbf{r}')}{|\textbf{r-r'}|^{1+\delta}}\right)=-\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{Q_{total}}{|\textbf{r-r'}|^{1+\delta}}\right)=(1+\delta)(\frac{Q_{total}}{r^{2+\delta}})$$

And this result just feels wrong, because it blows up at $r=0$, and it does not reduce to the "normal" case of $\delta =0$, $E=0$ inside. I know that I probably messed up the calculation badly, but as I don't usually have this kind of notation, I am quite lost as to how to approach it.

Comment: A homogeneous distribution in what shape?

Comment: it is not specified, only that it is a "homogeneous distribution of superficial charge"

Comment: The second equality in your second equation is wrong because you integrated the numerator ignoring the $\mathbf{r}’$ in the denominator.

Comment: I don’t know what superficial charge is. Does your text make that clear somewhere?

Comment: I was thinking about that integration step, but I'm not sure how to do it, as I don't really know what exactly my "r"s are, so I kind of ignored it because it made sense from the dimensions (As the potential should be 1/r). As to the superficial charge thing, it is not specified more than what I wrote, all I'm told is that it is on the surface of the object.

Comment: OK, so it’s surface charge. How about just assuming charge spread evenly on the surface of a sphere, and doing the integral?

Comment: Yes, I will try that now and edit back in when I get the integral, but I am not sure how to do it, as the factor of 1/|r-r'| confuses me more than it should. Once I figure it out I'll edit it back in

Comment: In MathJax, $\nabla$ is \$\nabla\$.

Comment: Oh you are correct, I had not noticed that mistake. Thanks!